# Where can I see the real rank of a player?

Tags: starcraft-2

I see a lot of people referring to players as *2500 diamond* for example.

Where can I see this rank?
All I found was the position within the division, but not that number that seems to be global (by region? In the world?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there is no source for the ranks used to match people, but you can see what the current point value of specific people if you have access to their league.

There are [helpful sources](http://sc2ranks.com/) for aggregating this information.

Comment: And the upcoming Pro leagues will make it easy to compare the "best" players soon enough.

Comment: @Raven maybe... I'm not holding out hope right now.  Most top players don't ladder to begin with so its hard to image those leagues will be meaningful.

Comment: @Tzenes -- I agree, hence "best". Just mentioning the upcoming functionality.

Comment: Why do the top players not play ladder? And what do they play? Only custom games with people they know?

Comment: Isn't this determined by ladder games? http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/1026297

Comment: @juan. Yes that list comes directly from ladder games, however youll notice a lot of the big names are either not on it or significantly lower than you might expect (Huk) being the exception. Partly this is because it's easier to hide your bo in custom games, but mostly because ladder doesn't let you choose your opponent